# How do I read an integer from a file, and then read that many lines after the integer in that file (Python)?

Tags: python, file, loops

I'm having some trouble with this problem. I'm a beginner to Python and have been searching this website but can't seem to figure out how to do this specific problem. If I have a file that looks something like this:

```
3
Alpha
Beta
Gamma
4
Delta
Epsilon
Omega
Zeta
```

I want to read that first integer (in this case, 3 but it could vary) and print it, and then read the next three lines (Alpha, Beta, Gamma) and print those. After that, I would want to read the next integer (in this case, 4) and then read the next four lines (Delta, Epsilon, Omega, Zeta) and print those.

I think I've figured out how to do it if that integer is fixed, but I'm not sure how to do it if that integer is a variable and could be anything. Here is what I have for if the integer is fixed:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == '3':  
            print "3"
            break
# Reads text until the end of the block:
    for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
        if line.strip() == '3':
            break
        print line
```

I would put this in a while loop that loops over the whole file, reading (and printing) an integer x, reading (and printing) the next x lines, then reading integer y, reading the next y lines, etc. Since I could be dealing with big files, it seems like reading line by line is the way to go with f.readline(), so after I read the first integer and numbers after it, I should read the next one.

Any help would be appreciated a lot. Thanks!

edit:

I would want to read from the file that has my data (3 Alpha Beta Gamma 4 etc). I would then read 3 (or any integer), which would then signal to read Alpha Beta Gamma. I would then write this to a file. Then, I would read 4 (or any integer again), which would then signal to read Delta Epsilon Omega Zeta. I would go through the rest of the file like this.

I have some idea for the individual parts, so after reading from file "myfile.txt", I would write this output to "output.txt":

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as fin:
alllines = fin.readlines();
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for i in range(len(alllines)):
            fout.write(alllines[i]);
```

I could also just do fin.readline() and read it line by line.

Comment: I notice a pattern: you are printing *every line*.  Why not just `for line in input_data: print line,`?

Comment: To test if a string is an integer, use `line.isdigit()`.

Comment: I'd like to eventually print every line eventually though. Basically, I want to print the first block (3, Alpha, beta, Gamma) and put that in a file and then print the second block (4, Delta, etc.) and put that in a file, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "put them in a file"?  I don't know what goes in which file(s).  Also, can you post what you've tried?  This site is a help site, so people want to see what you've tried first

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to read a file that is perfectly formatted such that the first line is a number N, the next N lines after the first are words to print, and the line after that is a number M, and the next M lines are the ones you want to print (and on and on), then the following would work:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as input_data:
    lines_to_print = int(input_data.readline().strip())
        for x in xrange(lines_to_print):  
            print input_data.readline()
```

This only works in the hypothetical case you presented.

This would print :

```
Alpha
Beta
Gamma
Delta
Epsilon
Omega
Zeta
```

Although, if your goal is to print *everything* that's not a number, then you could also do this:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if not line.isdigit():
            print line
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Basically my goal is to print: 

3
Alpha 
Beta
Gamma.

I would then write this into a file, and then go ahead and print:

4
Delta
etc.

So I do want to print the number as well at the top of each line, but I want to keep these all separately/in separate files.

Comment: @user6496380 You should post what you've tried so I can help guide you

Comment: Hi, I just made an edit showing what I mean by reading from one file, take the specific lines, and writing it to another file. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear (to me) what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to print every line, and write every non-number line to a file?

Comment: So this is what I'm trying to do: Let's say myfile.txt contains those lines seen in my original post (3 Alpha ..). I want to read that integer, 3, and then read the next 3 (or however many lines depending on the integer), and then write all those lines to another file. Then, I would go to the next block and in this case, read that 4, read the next 4 lines, and then write all these lines to another file. Does that make sense?

Comment: So there are two files, one input and one output?  And the output (in this case) would have "Alpha Beta Gamma Delta Epsilon etc" all on separate lines?

Comment: Yeah so the input file has everything I have in my first block in my original post. But the output file would only have (3 Alpha Beta Gamma), and then the next output file would have (4 Delta Epsilon etc).

Comment: Are there multiple output files or just one?

Comment: There would be multiple output files, i.e. one with (3 Alpha Beta Gamma), one with (4 Delta Epsilon etc.) and so on, so forth.

Comment: Well, although I could do it FOR you, I think it'd be more useful to you if I guided you instead.  You seem to know enough about Python to figure it out yourself with some help

Comment: Hey thanks for the general help and responses! I actually figured out how I would do this and print it out to different files using try, to figure out if the first line is an integer and then reading the next few lines in the range of the length of that integer. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem!  Can you accept the answer that you found most useful?  Thanks

Comment: I did, but it said I need more reputation before it will show up. Hopefully that should be soon!

Comment: Did you click the green checkmark, or the orange vote triangle?  It should be the green checkmark: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: Either way if it doesn't work don't worry about it :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to edit my original answer, so here's a new one instead.

Step one is to open and read the file, line by line:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as input_data:
    while True:
        line = input_data.readline()
        print line
        if not line:
            break
        ## this is where you do stuff, like file writing and whatnot
```

`if not line:` will exit the loop if there's no more lines.  In your "do stuff" section above, first thing is to check if it's a number:

```
        ## lineIsANumber = (check if "line" is a number)
```

If it is a number, then start another loop

```
        if lineIsANumber:
            for x in xrange(number_read_from_file):
                ## read next line
                ## print line
                ## write to a file
```

The tricky part is writing to a different file each time.  One thing you can do is name your files "1" "2" etc... for the order that they're created.  You can use an int and increment it each time lineIsANumber is true.  You would need to keep track of this in the main loop, the `while True` at the top level.

If you try this and get stuck I can help further